# What are the available estimators which we can use as estimator in onevsrest classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to know briefly about all the available estimators like logisticregression or multinomial regression or SVMs which can be used for classification problems.
These are the three I know. Are there any others like these? and relatively how long they run or how accurate can they get than these?

Answer (score 1):

Logistic Regression: It is a statistical for binary classification. Its not a classifier it used for predicting the probability of classification. It accept the answer in binary either true or false. Some threshold is decided using regresion and accordingly, the model decide the classification. 
Mathematics will help you to understand the difference

The logistic regression can be understood simply as finding the β parameters that best fit:

```
y = { 1      β 0 + β 1 x + ε > 0 
      0      else
```

where ε is an error distributed by the standard logistic distribution.

Multinominal Regression: It is a classification technique that generalized Logistic Regeression to multicast probelms. Input is dependent in this case and method trys to find the best possible nearest line through the input. Basic idea is calculating score usig dot product from all the possible input and finding the nearest possible solution.

Support Vector Machine : It is non-linear classifier. SVM is a representation of points in space, mapped so that the points are classified in seperate categories and wiht a clear gap which wide as possible and can be used further for new points.

There are many classification tecniques and depending on the data we use the classifier. I would refer MIT opencourseware for the same.I guess this will help you too get the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used for classification problems:

- Logistic Regression
- SVM
- RandomForest Classifier
- Neural Networks